# Generating RDoc to LaTeX

Tags: ruby, latex, rdoc, yard

Is it possible to generate RDoc in LaTeX format? I looked at RDoc and YARD, but didn't find what I need.

I am writing a documentation in LaTeX for my project in Ruby, and I need a way to easily embed the API reference, as an appendix or as a chapter, in the final PDF. The most convenient, for me, would be to generate LaTeX source from Ruby source files and include it where appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

I have no experience with it, but a short google-search shows:

- https://github.com/Quintus/rdoc_pdf-latex  (link broken, see below)
- http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9/classes/RDoc/Markup/ToLaTeX.html (link broken)

Another possibility:
DO you know the listings-package in LaTeX? There is also a ruby support.
You would get no rdoc-commands, but maybe you could make LaTeX-commands in your code?

---

[Papyrus](http://devel.pegasus-alpha.eu/projects/papyrus) is a plugin for RDoc that enables RDoc to generate PDF files. It's based on LaTeX. So there should be a intermediate TeX-file.

From the [readme.rdoc](https://github.com/Quintus/Papyrus/blob/master/README.rdoc) of the [github repository for papyrus](https://github.com/Quintus/Papyrus):

> This library is a plugin for Ruby’s documentation generator RDoc. It provides both a generator for outputting PDF (Portable document format) (the RDoc::Generator::Papyrus class) files and a formatter for turning the parsed RDoc markup into LaTeX code (RDoc::Markup::ToLaTeX; RDoc::Markup::ToLaTeX_Crossref adds cross-reference facilities).

Comment: I have seen the second link, but I have no idea how to use it in practice. The second one is meant to produce PDFs, but I'll take a look whether it's possible to get the raw LaTeX output.

I actually use the listings package to provide code examples, but I need something more automatic.

Comment: Both of these links are broken now, sadly.

Comment: @mohawkjohn: I added another source.